# How do I color plot.ly js legend and why is it black?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

When my graph renders, everything is great EXCEPT the legend only shows the colors black. The grouped bar chart graph is displaying how I would expect. All of the data and colors are wonderful, but the legend is not right.

I am loading a plotly graph into a salesforce Visualforce page as follows:

```
    <apex:panelGroup styleClass="charts" layout="block">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</apex:panelGroup>
<script>
    var trace1 = {
      y: ['B2B', 'Commercial', 'Retail'], 
      x: [20, 14, 23],
      marker: {
          color: ['#f8b98d', '#f8b98d', '#f8b98d']  
      },
      name: 'Annual Quota', 
      type: 'bar',
      orientation: 'h'  

    };

    var trace2 = {
      y: ['B2B', 'Commercial', 'Retail'], 
      x: [12, 18, 29],
      marker: {
          color: ['#f58b3f', '#f58b3f', '#f58b3f']  
      },
      name: 'Current Market Size', 
      type: 'bar',
      orientation: 'h'

    };

    var data = [trace1, trace2];

    var layout = {barmode: 'group'};

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to this - custom colours on stacked bars looked great, but the legend swatches all black.

I couldn't find an official solution, so manually set the colours in the legend after the chart was generated using Plotly's built in d3, e.g:

```
var legendBoxes = document.getElementById("div-id-for-plot").getElementsByClassName("legendbar");
Plotly.d3.select(legendBoxes[0]).style("fill", "put your colour definition here");
```

(this example just styles a single box)